# Regex assistance needed

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to build a regex in PHP to extract the first part of the sample strings below. The angle brackets denotes required part, square brackets denotes the optional part, and there are three possibilities of input (the brackets are not included in the input).

- `<Rua Olavo Bilac>`
- `<Rua Olavo Bilac>[ - de 123...]`
- `<Rua Olavo Bilac>[ - até ...]`

(beware that the required part may have dashes)

I've tried:

`/(.*?)( - (de|até){1,1}.*)?/i` (the first group should capture what I needed, ungreedily)

I`ve also tried several modifications without luck. I'm probably doing some confusion here, specially with the groups and with the quantity modifiers. From what I understand:

1. The first group would catch any character, ungreedly
2. The second group, optional per the `?` modifier, would have `\s-\s` followed by one of the two words `de` or `até` exactly one time, then any characters until the end of the line.

I ended replacing preg_match_all with strpos and substr, testing for each possibility. It did work, but I need to understand where I'm wrong about the regex approach.

Comment: I understand that the title may look uninformative or too generic, but I really couldn't find a better option (thought of "help with regex", "can't make regex work", etc).

Comment: Consider "Rua Olavo Bilac[ - de 123...]". The entire string would match the first group, as the second group is optional. Both groups have numbers, letters, spaces, etc. So I can't see a single regex that does the job.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know it works! Hey btw, I notice you haven't yet voted on StackOverflow. If this answer and for any answer you find helpful, please consider voting up as this is how the reputation system works. No obligation, of course! Thanks for listening to my 10-second SO rep tutorial. :)

Comment: You said you can have a dash in the first part. See the new regex, new demo, new explanation. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/eW2iO6)):

```
^.*(?= *-(?!.*-))|^.*
```

**How does it work?**

1. We match two kinds of string, on either side of the `|`
2. On the left side, from the head of the string (anchored by the `^` assertion), the dot-star `.*` eats up any characters up to a place where the lookahead `(?= *-(?!.*-))` asserts that what follows is optional space characters `*` and a dash `-`, not followed by (negative lookahead) more characters and a dash.
3. On the right side of the `|`, we match anything.

This assume that you are checking the strings line by line. If that is not the case, let us know.

**Sample Code**

```
$regex = "~^.*(?= *-(?!.*-))|^.*~";
if(preg_match($regex,$string,$m)) echo $m[0];
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't made it clear enough, the brackets are not part of the input.

Comment: @DanielCosta Okay, made a new regex. :)

Comment: Almost there, I changed it to `^(.*?)(?:$|\s*-)` to separate the input. You did solve the question for the sample input but then I thought about strings that may have dashes in the first portion. I will take this answer as accepted anyway.

Comment: @DanielCosta FYI, in the last version I am not using `\s` for safety as it can match new lines as well as spaces (see demo, code etc).